# Can't show correctly views added at runtime

Tags: android, user-interface, layout-inflater, android-inflate

This is my main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout style="@style/StandardFillWrap" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/match_tab"
        style="@style/StandardFillWrap"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_name" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_score" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_name" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_score" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/match_filter_b"
        style="@style/StandardFillWrap"
        android:layout_below="@id/match_tab"
        android:text="@string/l_matchView_filters" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/match_list"
        style="@style/StandardWrapWrap" 
        android:layout_below="@id/match_filter_b"
        />
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/match_reparti"
        style="@style/StandardFillWrap"
        android:layout_below="@id/match_list"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/match_home_name_det"
                style="@style/NomePlayer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView android:text="@string/vuoto" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_indirect_set_pieces" />

            <TextView android:text="@string/vuoto" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_defence" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_set_def" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_attack" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_set_att" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/vuoto" />

            <TextView android:text="@string/vuoto" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_team_attitude" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_team_attitude" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_tactic" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_team_tactic" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_tactic_skill" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_team_tactic_skill" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/vuoto" />

            <TextView android:text="@string/vuoto" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_midfield" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_team_midfield" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_right_defence" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_team_r_def" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_central_defence" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_team_c_def" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_left_defence" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_team_l_def" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_right_attack" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_team_r_att" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_central_attack" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_team_c_att" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_left_attack" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_home_team_l_att" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/match_away_name_det"
                style="@style/NomePlayer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView android:text="@string/vuoto" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_indirect_set_pieces" />

            <TextView android:text="@string/vuoto" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_defence" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_set_def" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_attack" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_set_att" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/vuoto" />

            <TextView android:text="@string/vuoto" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_team_attitude" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_team_attitude" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_tactic" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_team_tactic" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_tactic_skill" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_team_tactic_skill" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/vuoto" />

            <TextView android:text="@string/vuoto" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_midfield" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_team_midfield" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_right_defence" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_team_r_def" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_central_defence" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_team_c_def" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_left_defence" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_team_l_def" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_right_attack" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_team_r_att" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_central_attack" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_team_c_att" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow >

            <TextView android:text="@string/l_matchView_left_attack" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/match_away_team_l_att" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And method filling up `match_list` is:

```
private void mimicListAdapter(List<Event> eventsList, String filters) {

    TextView minute;
    ImageView event_key;
    TextView event_text;
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.match_list); 

    for(Event p:eventsList) {
        //LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.match_event, null, true);
        minute = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.minute);
        event_key = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_img);
        event_text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.event_text);
        boolean found = false;
        String[] events = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.filtering);
        if(filters!=null)
        {
            if(filters!="")
            {
                char[] indici = filters.toCharArray();
                for(int i = 0; i<indici.length; i++){
                    if(events[Character.getNumericValue( indici[i] )].contains(","+p.getEventKey()+","))
                    {
                        found=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }   
            }

        }
        minute.setText(Integer.toString(p.getMinute()));
        event_text.setText(p.getEventText());
        try {
            Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable( getResources().getIdentifier("i_"+p.getEventKey(), "drawable", getPackageName()));
            event_key.setImageDrawable(img);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if(found) {
            event_text.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
            minute.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);
            found = false;
        }   

        container.addView(rowView);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that whatever is outside `match_list` is shown correctly,inside match_list I can see the first element but then it's all blank. I mean che LinearLayout appears to be filled up because occupies a lot of the display but it's just black space with only the first `Event` visible.

Answer (score 1):

When adding a view to a container you should pass information about how it must be displayed using LayoutParams class. Right now you are missing the information that would have been otherwise defined in the layout xml with layout_widht and layout_height. Without them I guess Android sets up the first view but fails to align the others as the size information is missing. Something like this:

```
container.addView(rowView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Nope...same problem. It's quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really an idiot. I missed the vertical orientation of the LinearLayout.

BTW I found out listening to this Google I/O about ListView. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70